# Bootstrap 2 columns one needs to scroll while other fixed position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, overflow

So I have a very specific design that involves 2 columns inside of a box.

The left column will stay within the height bounds of the box but the right column will be longer and thus require scrolling. I am using bootstrap and need to get the right column to scroll without the left one moving.

I've already tried making the box overflow:scroll but obviously that scrolls both columns. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

html:

```
<div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 outer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 leftcol">
                    This content needs to stay put while scrolling (aka fixed)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 rightcol">
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                    This content Scrolls<br>This content Scrolls<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
    border:solid 1px #000;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.leftcol {
    border:solid 1px green;
}

.rightcol {
    border:solid 1px red;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:200px; /* I WANT THIS TO BE IMPLIED RATHER THAN STATIC */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snoapps/z8h0drsb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took out the overflow hidden on the wrapper but gave `.rightcol` a height and then applied `overflow-y: scroll` to it.

CSS:

```
.outer {
    border:solid 1px #000;
    height:200px;
}

.leftcol {
  /* position: fixed;
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%; */
   border:solid 1px green;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.rightcol {
   /* border:solid 1px red;
   position: relative;
   top: 0%;
   left: 50%;  */
   border:solid 1px red; 
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Left is fixed, right scrolls off the screen.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/jbpmYE)

I hope I understood you correctly, if not just comment and I'll update!

Comment: This is close. The reason it doesn't work is because the left column is position:fixed causing it to stay in that spot on the screen even if the page scrolls. I meant for the column to stay "fixed" inside the '.outer' div and the right column to scroll within the '.outer' div (aka the right column has its own scroll bars)

Comment: I updated my question with code that works, but I want the .rightcol to have a dynamic height that matches the outer's height (inherit doesn't work)

Comment: I updated the codepen, I took out the ``overflow:hidden`` on the wrapper and gave the div on the right a height with a ``overflow-y: scroll;``

Comment: Yes, that's what I want but without a statically set 200px height to the rightcol div. I was hoping there was a way to make the rightcol have the same height as the container div without explicitly defining it

Comment: Even without the height expressed in the outer div but an expressed height on ``.rightcol`` it will end up being the same height as the outer div.

Comment: Why are some of the properties commented?